# Корзина на чистом js

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-events

Даны 3 блока

В левой части страницы – перечень категорий.
При нажатии на категорию в средний блок выводится перечень продуктов данной категории.
Клик на товар – информацию о товаре в правом блоке.
В информации товара – кнопка “купить”.
При нажатии на “купить” появляется сообщение, что товар куплен и возвращен в исходное состояние программы (когда отображается только список категорий). С последним пунктом возникли проблемы, как это можно реализовать? Чтобы при нажатии ок в алерт откат назад, и пользователь видит только категории товаров

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('wrapper');
const product = document.createElement('div');
product.classList.add('product');
const list = document.createElement('div');
list.classList.add('list');
const priceInfo = document.createElement('div');
priceInfo.classList.add('price-info');
const body = document.body;
body.appendChild(div);
div.append(product, list, priceInfo);
const header = document.createElement('h1');
header.textContent = 'Добро пожаловать в наш магазин!';
div.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', header);
header.classList.add('title');
const ul = `
    <ul>
        <li><button class="btn" data-data-id="meat">Meat</button></li>
        <li><button class="btn" data-data-id="bread">Bread</button></li>
        <li><button class="btn" data-data-id="fish">Fish</button></li>
    </ul>
`;


product.innerHTML = ul;
const data = {
    meat: [
        {name: 'bacon', count: 21, quality: 'excellent'},
        {name: 'beef', count: 12, quality: 'excellent'},
        {name: 'chiken', count: 7,quality: 'excellent'}
    ],
    bread: [
        {name: 'baguette', count: 23, quality: 'excellent'},
        {name: 'sponge cake', count: 20, quality: 'excellent'},
        {name: 'quiche', count: 41, quality: 'excellent'},
        {name: 'pitta breade', count: 7, quality: 'excellent'}
    ],
    fish: [
        {name: 'anchovy', count: 23, quality: 'excellent'},
        {name: 'cod', count: 20, quality: 'excellent'},
        {name: 'pilcharde', count: 41, quality: 'excellent'},
        {name: 'plaice', count: 7, quality: 'excellent'}
    ]
}
   

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const productId = button.dataset.dataId;
      const productList = data[productId];
      const productNames = productList.map(product => product.name);
      list.textContent = '';
      productNames.forEach(name => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = name;
        list.appendChild(li);
  
        const buyButton = document.createElement('button');
        buyButton.textContent = 'Купить';
        buyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const productInfo = productList.find(product => product.name === name);
        alert(`Вы купили ${productInfo.name}!`);
        });
  
        const card = document.createElement('div');
        card.classList.add('product-card');
        card.innerHTML = `
        <h2>${name}</h2>
        <p>Count: ${productList.find(product => product.name === name).count}</p>
        <p>Quality: ${productList.find(product => product.name === name).quality}</p>
             
        `;
        card.appendChild(buyButton);
  
        li.addEventListener('click', () => {
        priceInfo.textContent = '';
        priceInfo.appendChild(card);
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  };


.ul {
  list-style: none;
}; 


.product, .list,.price-info {
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: #e3b4dc;
} 


.btn, button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #413939;
  background-color: #bca1b5;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  margin: 10px;  
 
};
.product-count, .product-quality {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - создать функцию, которая будет очищать содержимое блока `priceInfo` и заполнять блок `product` списком категорий. Затем вызвать эту функцию в обработчике клика на кнопке "купить".

Пример:

```
const clearProductInfo = () => {
    priceInfo.innerHTML = '';
    product.innerHTML = ul;
};

const ul = `
    <ul>
        <li><button class="btn" data-data-id="meat">Meat</button></li>
        <li><button class="btn" data-data-id="bread">Bread</button></li>
        <li><button class="btn" data-data-id="fish">Fish</button></li>
    </ul>
`;

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const productId = button.dataset.dataId;
        const productList = data[productId];
        const productNames = productList.map(product => product.name);
        list.innerHTML = '';
        productNames.forEach(name => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent = name;
            list.appendChild(li);

            const buyButton = document.createElement('button');
            buyButton.textContent = 'Купить';
            buyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const productInfo = productList.find(product => product.name === name);
                alert(`Вы купили ${productInfo.name}!`);
                clearProductInfo();
            });

            const card = document.createElement('div');
            card.classList.add('product-card');
            card.innerHTML = `
                <h2>${name}</h2>
                <p class="product-count">Count: ${productList.find(product => product.name === name).count}</p>
                <p class="product-quality">Quality: ${productList.find(product => product.name === name).quality}</p>
            `;
            card.appendChild(buyButton);

            li.addEventListener('click', () => {
                priceInfo.innerHTML = '';
                priceInfo.appendChild(card);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: cкрипт не работает. в консоли выбивает ошибку -  buttons is not defined, прописываю const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'); перед buttons.forEach(button => { Скрипт не запускается и ошибку в консоли не выбивает